# WebDAV java client with OAuth2, Basic, NTLM or Negotiate Authentication mechanism

Tags: google-api, google-http-client

Does `google-http-java-client` library will help to support WebDAV using OAuth2, Basic, NTLM or Negotiate Authentication mechanism?